# A command call implemented in C, called from TeX via Lua. Why is it hanging?

Tags: luatex, lua

The following C code (`popen3luatex.c`) implements a command call at the C level.

This can be called from LuaTeX using the LaTeX file `popen3luatex.tex`, below `popen3luatex.c`.

I've written little C code for the past 20 years, so this C code is probably buggy and stylistically poorly written, but mostly works as
expected. (Suggestions for improvement gratefully appreciated.)

However, the option

```
cmd = {"lsx", "-la", "zarko.tex"}
```

hangs the TeX compilation. Ctrl-C does drop it to a prompt, but that shouldn't be necessary. `strace` shows that it is hanging at a read call, but beyond that, I don't know why it is hanging. So, that is my question. Why is this code hanging?

The other choices I've used for `cmd` cause TeX to error out normally at a prompt.

The LaTeX compilation can be invoked as

```
lualatex -shell-escape popen3luatex.tex
```

Alternatively, one can call the embedded Lua directly with

```
texlua popen3luatex.lua
```

This version does not hang with that version of cmd.

Also, if LUATEX is not defined, i.e. `#define LUATEX 1` is commented out, this should reduce to a normal Lua module, and then can just be
called with

```
lua5.3 popen3luatex.lua
```

This does not hang either.

Some notes and comments about the C code. I realise this isn't a C programming forum, but no harm in asking for feedback.

1. Why did I write this function? Because Lua
   doesn't offer anything adequate for the
   purpose. The closest is `popen` from the
   [Lua POSIX library](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix), which (I
   think) is mostly a wrapper for the POSIX C
   function `popen`. But the Lua `popen` is
   inadequate, and Lua POSIX is in any case a
   third party library. While I could make do
   with `popen`, its deficiencies are annoying.
   Also, it was an opportunity to practice
   writing C code and learn a litle about
   POSIX.
2. I got the list of the different ways a child
   can terminate from Stevens' "Advanced
   Programming in the UNIX programming" 3rd
   Edition, Section 8.6 (Fig. 8.4). They are:
   WIFEXITED, WIFSIGNALED, WIFSTOPPED, and
   WIFCONTINUED. WIFSTOPPED and WIFCONTINUED
   seemed unlikely conditions to encounter in
   practice, and in fact I left off
   WIFCONTINUED, which seemed the least likely
   of all. I realise this is an arbitrary
   decision, but I'm not aware of what best
   practices, if any, are for this situation.
   If you have recommendations, please let me
   know.
3. This code has some error checks, but it's
   possible it should have more. If you think
   I've bolloxed up a check, or you think there
   should be additional checks, please let me
   know.
4. I didn't attempt to deallocate dynamically
   allocated memory, partly because for such a
   small program it would get deallocated soon
   enough, so it didn't seem to matter. Also, I
   had difficulty figuring out how to without
   making the code even more complicated.
   Thoughts about the optimal strategy to
   employ here would be appreciated.
5. This code builds the Lua module by invoking

   ```
   os.execute("gcc -Wall -o popen3luatex.so -shared -fpic  popen3luatex.c -I/usr/include/lua5.3/ -llua5.3")
   ```

   at the beginning of the Lua code. There may
   be better ways to do so, but I currently
   don't know of any.
6. I was undecided which of TeX SE, U&L SE, or
   StackOverflow to post this question to. The
   LuaTeX mailing list is also a possibility.
   Since it's technically a TeX question, I
   thought I'd try it here first. If it doesn't
   get replies here, perhaps StackOverflow
   would be a good place to try next.
7. If the C code writes to standard error, this
   gets sent by TeX to standard output. This
   doesn't happen with Lua, or even the
   embedded Lua in LuaTeX that is invoked by
   `texlua`. Is there anything that can be done
   about this, or is this just how TeX works?

Code follows.

```
############################################
popen3luatex.c
############################################

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 4096

#define LUATEX 1

// Writes to standard output and TeX log file.
static int writeout (lua_State *L, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
#if defined(LUATEX)// use texio.write_nl.
  char *msg;
  int size = vasprintf(&msg, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (size == -1)
    luaL_error(L, "asprint exited with error");

  lua_getglobal(L, "texio");
  lua_getfield(L, -1, "write_nl");
  lua_remove(L, -2);
  lua_pushstring(L, msg);
  lua_call(L, 1, 0);
#else// send to standard error
  int size = vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if (size == -1)
    luaL_error(L, "vfprint exited with error");
#endif

  return 1;
}

char * append_strings(const char * old, const char * new)
{
    // find the size of the string to allocate
    const size_t old_len = strlen(old), new_len = strlen(new);
    const size_t out_len = old_len + new_len + 1;

    // allocate a pointer to the out string
    char *out = malloc(out_len);

    // concat both strings and return
    memcpy(out, old, old_len);
    memcpy(out + old_len, new, new_len + 1);

    return out;
}

void luaerror(lua_State *L, const char* fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  char *msg;
  int size = vasprintf(&msg, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  if (size == -1)
    luaL_error(L, "asprint exited with error");
  luaL_error(L, msg);
}

int popen3_c(lua_State *L, char * cmd[])
{
  int fda[2], fdb[2], fdc[2];

  assert((pipe(fda) == 0) && (pipe(fdb) == 0) && (pipe(fdc) == 0));

  int r1 = fda[0]; int w1 = fda[1];
  int r2 = fdb[0]; int w2 = fdb[1];
  int r3 = fdc[0]; int w3 = fdc[1];

  //pid_t parent = getpid();
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1) // fork failed
    {
      luaerror(L, "Error. Failed to fork().\n");
    }
  else if (pid > 0)
    {
      close(r1);
      close(w2);
      close(w3);

      char *stdoutstr = "";
      char *stderrstr = "";
      char line[MAXLINE];
      FILE *fdstdout, *fdstderr;

      // Return early if file cannot be opened.
      if ((fdstdout = fdopen(r2, "r")) == NULL) {
    luaerror(L, "Error: Couldn't open r2: errno is %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      }

      while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fdstdout) != NULL)
    stdoutstr = append_strings(stdoutstr, line);
      if((stdoutstr[0] != '\0') && (stdoutstr != NULL))
    writeout(L, "command stdout is: %s\n", stdoutstr);
      fclose(fdstdout);

      // Return early if file cannot be opened.
      if ((fdstderr = fdopen(r3, "r")) == NULL) {
    luaerror(L, "Error: Couldn't open r3: errno is %d (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
      }

      while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fdstderr) != NULL)
    stderrstr = append_strings(stderrstr, line);
      if((stderrstr[0] != '\0') && (stderrstr != NULL))
    writeout(L, "command stderr is: %s\n", stderrstr);
      fclose(fdstderr);

      int status;
      int waitreturnval = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      if(waitreturnval > 0)
    {
      char *msg;
      int size = asprintf(&msg, "wait exited with process ID of the terminated child %d\n", waitreturnval);
      if (size == -1)
        luaL_error(L, "asprint exited with error");
      writeout(L, msg);
    }
      else if(waitreturnval == -1)
    luaerror(L, "wait exited with error");
      else if(waitreturnval == 0)
        luaerror(L, "wait exited with code %d\n", waitreturnval);
      if(WIFEXITED(status)) // Child terminated normally
    {
      if(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
        writeout(L, "Child exited normally. Exit code is %d. Exit success. \n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
      else
        luaerror(L, "Child exited normally. Exit code is %d. Exit failure. \n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    else if(WIFSIGNALED(status))// Child terminated abnormally, by
                                // receipt of a signal it didn't
                                // catch.
    luaerror(L, "Child terminated abnormally. Signal number is %d", WTERMSIG(status));
      else if(WIFSTOPPED(status))
    luaerror(L, "Child is currently stopped. Signal number that caused the child to stop is %d", WSTOPSIG(status));
      close(w1);
    }
  else // child
    {
      close(w1);
      close(r2);
      close(r3);

      dup2(r1, fileno(stdin));
      dup2(w2, fileno(stdout));
      dup2(w3, fileno(stderr));

      int ret = execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
      char *cmdstring = "\"";
      for(int i=0; cmd[i]!=(char *)NULL; i++)
    {
      cmdstring = append_strings(cmdstring, cmd[i]);
      if(cmd[i+1]!=(char *)NULL)
        cmdstring = append_strings(cmdstring, " ");
      if(cmd[i+1]==(char *)NULL)
        cmdstring = append_strings(cmdstring, "\"");
    }
      // If the program continues past this point, it means `execvp`
      // returned, which only happens if `execp` encountered an error.
      luaerror(L, "execlp called on command string %s returned %d, errno is %d (%s)\n", cmdstring, ret, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
  return 0;
}

static int popen3_wrapper(lua_State *L)
{
  int n = lua_gettop(L);    /* number of arguments */
  lua_len (L, n); // length of table at index n (top of stack).  The
                  // result is pushed on the stack.
  uint32_t numargs = (uint32_t)lua_tonumber (L, lua_gettop(L));
  for(int i=1; i <= numargs; i++)
    lua_geti (L, 1, i);
  lua_remove(L, 1); // remove original argument table
  lua_remove(L, 1); // remove numargs
  char *args[numargs+1];
  for(int i=1; i <= numargs; i++)
    args[i - 1] = (char *)lua_tostring(L, i);
  args[numargs] = (void *)NULL;
  popen3_c(L, args);
  return 1;
}

static const luaL_Reg myfuncs[] = {
  {"popen3", popen3_wrapper},
  {NULL, NULL},
};

int luaopen_popen3luatex(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_newlib(L, myfuncs);

  return 1;
}
#################################################
```

and

```
#################################################
popen3luatex.tex         
#################################################
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{p3luatex.lua}
os.execute("gcc -Wall -o popen3luatex.so -shared -fpic  popen3luatex.c -I/usr/include/lua5.3/ -llua5.3")
local popen3luatex = require "popen3luatex"

--cmd = {"tput", "tput", "foo"}
--cmd = {"sh", "-c", "./nopath"}
--cmd = {"ls", "-lah", "/nopath"}
-- -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59383972#59383972
-- cmd = {"sh", "-c", "exit 17"}
-- The following command hangs
cmd = {"lsx", "-la", "zarko.tex"}
--cmd = {"ls", "-la", "zarko.tex"}
--cmd = {"wkhtmltopdf", "searchpath(foo.html)", "foo.pdf"}

-- Both the TeX and pure Lua versions of this command hang if an
-- internet connection is not available.
-- cmd = {"wkhtmltopdf", "foo.html", "foo.pdf"}

popen3luatex.popen3(cmd)
\end{filecontents}
\directlua{local p3luatex = require "p3luatex"}

\end{document}
```